# Why does root take ownership of my files?

Tags: libraries, git, ownership

I'm new to Linux and trying to install a library from Github.

I cloned https://github.com/AngryLawyer/rust-sdl2 in `/home/username/documents/` and ran make as per instructions. Now the entire `rust-sdl2` folder is owned by `root` and I can't make any changes.

Why is this happening? Should I have put lib files into a particular folder? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you run make as sudo? This will cause sudo (the root user) to own that directory.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20953/difference-between-make-install-and-sudo-make-install

Comment: I'm pretty sure I did.

Comment: Try to install it again without doing "sudo make", I took a look at the instructions on the github site that you linked to and unless I missed it, I did not see that they required the use of sudo make install.

Comment: How do I get ownership of rust-sdl2 back?

Comment: You can use chmod and change the ownership from your root to your user. Take a look at this great document on file permissions in Ubuntu. It includes documentation on how to use the chmod command. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions

Answer (score 3):

You can not change the owner as root without superuser permissions.  Probably you downloaded the file as superuser or  you ran `make` command as superuser.

Anyway, if you want to change the owner of the files, type (change `username` with yours):

```
sudo chown -R username:username /path/to/change
```